# Problem to increase disk space on centOS

Tags: linux, centos

```
[root@smm ~]# grep -i swaptotal /proc/meminfo
SwapTotal:           0 kB

[root@smm ~]# grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz

[root@smm ~]# df -k /dev/shm
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                 16639508         0  16639508   0% /dev/shm

[root@smm ~]# df -k /tmp
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2     10154020   9990680         0 100% /
```

Question goes like thiss...

How to increase the swap space i.e. upto 24GB... And how to increase disk space /tmp... we installed the fresh centOS linux and it is giving suchh output.. Please let me know on thiss...

Comment: 24GB is an insane amount of swap...

Answer (score 3):

I didn't understand well what you have to do.
To check swap:

```
#swapon -s

#cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i swap
```

To add a file or partition just use swapon(8)

PS: I forgot...to create a swap file or partition use mkswap(8)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show

df -h

Also do you have free space on the disks?

Comment: and are you using LVM?